# Problems with FnMut

Tags: web, rust, sys

I'm trying to learn WASM with Rust, and I'm using the `web_sys` library.

The page I'm working on has an input with `id`, `player_name_button` and a button with player_name_button. Following this tutorial [Closures](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/closures.html), when I try to put a behavior over the button click I got a compiler error:

```
   |
84 |               let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
   |  ___________________________________^
85 | |                 name_input_value = value(&mut Some(player_name_input));
86 | |                 if name_input_value == String::new() {
87 | |                     alert("Por favor informe o nome!");
...  |
93 | |                 }
94 | |             }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
   | |______________^ expected an `FnMut<()>` closure, found `[closure@src\lib.rs:84:44: 94:14 player_name_input:web_sys::features::gen_Element::Element, name_input_value:std::string::String, player_storage:player::player::PlayerSotorage]`
```

Here follows the code:

```
let player_name_input = document
    .get_element_by_id("player_name_input")
    .expect("should have #num-clicks on the page");

let mut name_input_value = String::new();
//

let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
    name_input_value = value(&mut Some(player_name_input));
    if name_input_value == String::new() {
        alert("Please informe the name!");
    } else {
        let mut p = Player {
            name: name_input_value,
        };
        player_storage.insert(p);
    }
}) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
document
    .get_element_by_id("player_name_button")
    .expect("should have #player_name_button on the page")
    .dyn_ref::<HtmlElement>()
    .expect("#player_name_button be an `HtmlElement`")
    .set_onclick(Some(a.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));

// See comments in `setup_clock` above for why we use `a.forget()`.
a.forget();
```

Here is the Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[build-dependencies]
askama = "0.7.2"

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.60"
js-sys = "0.3.37"
askama = "0.7.2"
console_error_panic_hook = "0.1.5"

[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3.5"
features = [
  'console',
  'CssStyleDeclaration',
  'Document',
  'DomStringMap',
  'DomTokenList',
  'Element',
  'Event',
  'EventTarget',
  'HtmlBodyElement',
  'HtmlElement',
  'HtmlInputElement',
  'KeyboardEvent',
  'Location',
  'Node',
  'NodeList',
  'Storage',
  'Window',
]

# The `console_error_panic_hook` crate provides better debugging of panics by
# logging them with `console.error`. This is great for development, but requires
# all the `std::fmt` and `std::panicking` infrastructure, so isn't great for
# code size when deploying.
console_error_panic_hook = { version = "0.1.1", optional = true }

# `wee_alloc` is a tiny allocator for wasm that is only ~1K in code size
# compared to the default allocator's ~10K. It is slower than the default
# allocator, however.
#
# Unfortunately, `wee_alloc` requires nightly Rust when targeting wasm for now.
wee_alloc = { version = "0.4.2", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
wasm-bindgen-test = "0.2"

[profile.release]
# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.
opt-level = "s"
```

Comment: I would guess that your closure is not `'static`, that is it is holding references to values in the stack (`player_storage` or `player_name_input`), and that is not allowed.

Comment: Would this be resolved through the use of `clone`?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

This is caused by one of two possible causes. I can't tell which one, but here they are:

1. The `player_name_input` or `name_input_value` variable is used after the closure.
2. The `player_name_input` variable contains a reference into `document`.

Both issues would cause the closure to not be `'static`, i.e. it would contain references to values stored outside of itself. This is a problem because `Box<dyn FnOnce()>` implicitly has a `Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'static>` requirement. In the first case, this is a reference to one of the variables, and in the second case it would be a reference into `document`.

Note that your comparison to `String::new()` can be replaced with an `.is_empty()`.